# How to detect that NYM is changed

Tags: python, tor, stem

I use Stem for controlling my tor. I need to know when tor changes it's IP. It usually happens when signal `NEWNYM` is sended to tor, but there can be some other reasons.

Maybe, easiest way is to check current tor IP and user-agent. But I don't know how to retreive it using Stem.

Maybe, tor fires some event when NYM is changed? If so, how can I subscribe for this?

Help me, please!

---

I tried this code, `event_handler` was executed several times and only after some http request was sended via tor. Is it possible to handle event like "NEWNYM received"?

```
def event_handler(event):
    print "HANDLED!!"
    print event

from stem.control import Controller
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import EventType

controller = Controller.from_port()
controller.authenticate(password=settings.TOR_PASSWORD)

controller.add_event_listener(event_handler, EventType.CIRC)

controller.signal('NEWNYM')

# if I comment this, event_handler will not be executed
import requests
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=settings.TOR_PROXIES)
print r.json()
```

Comment: subscribe with `controller.add_event_listener(event_handler, EventType.CircuitEvent)` where 'event_handler' is callback function.

Comment: I thied your solution, but I got unexpected results (see question update)